# Sort an arraylist using multiple conditions comparing item’s field with an external field

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist, kotlin

I want to sort an arraylist in below order-

1.On top show items with the Code exactly matching with the searched text.

2.Below that show items with the Name exactly matching with searched text.

3.Below that show items with the Code starting with the searched text.

4.Below that show items with the Name starting with the searched text.

5. Below that show items with the Name containing the searched text.

I used below code for this-

```
xyzArrayList.sortWith(compareBy<XYZ>{it.code==searchedText}.thenBy{it.name==searchedText}.thenBy {it.code?.startsWith(searchedText)}.thenBy{it.name?.startsWith(searchedText)}.thenBy { it.name?.contains(searchedText) })
```

But the above code doesn’t sort the list.Where am I going wrong and how can I achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, instead of using `sortWith` and `thenBy`, you could take advantage of another extension function on `Collections` called `partition`.

This function takes a predicate and creates a `Pair<List<T>, List<T>>` where the first list contains elements that match the predicate and the second list all the other elements.

Let's see an example:

```
val cities = ["Berlin", "London", "Paris", "Rome", "Budapest", "Barcelona"]

// Here we apply a predicate to create the first partition
val searchQuery = "B"
val (matchingElements, nonMatchingElements) 
     = cities.partition { it == searchQuery } //([], ["Berlin", "London", "Paris", "Rome", "Budapest", "Barcelona"]

// Now potentially we could create another partition from the nonMatchingElements list
val (startingWithQuery, others) = nonMatchingElements
    .partition { it.startsWith(searchQuery) }

println(matchingElements) // []
println(startingWithQuery) // ["Berlin", "Budapest", "Barcelona"]
println(others) // ["London", "Paris", "Rome"]
```

After having created all the partitions you need, you can now generate a list from all the partitions you need in the right order or show those different lists with some separator.